# PHP Foreach Tree Alternatives

Tags: php, json, foreach

This is a foreach tree that is common in my workflows when parsing JSON, but I can't help but think there is a better way. I've tried to look this up and I've found some people referring to array_walk but I don't see how that would eliminate the need to do foreach inside foreach inside foreach. Any help? If there's a better way, I'd love to learn because this is not always convenient and feels quite messy.

As requested in comments, the expected result would be to generate a page for each degree, but that page's template would use all of the name variables from the foreach tree (and some others that I didn't include). I stripped my PHP to keep the example simple, although I understand that my use case could effect how the question is answered so that's why I added that information.

Here's some PHP to parse the array:

```
foreach ($programs as $program) {
  $program_name = $program['name'];
  $degrees = program['degrees'];
  foreach ($degrees as $degree) {
    $degree_name = $degree['name'];
    $courses = $degree['courses'];
    foreach ($courses as $course) {
      $course_name = $course['name'];
      echo $course_name;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the JSON:

```
{
  "programs":{
    "undergraduate":{
      "name":"undergraduate",
      "degrees":{
        "elementary education":{
          "name":"elementary education",
          "courses":{
            "math":{
              "name":"math"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: show the initial input and expected result

Comment: Hey RomanPerekhrest, I updated my question with a more specific example. In this situation, I've used the hierarchy to generate a page for each program, degree, and course. Although in my example, I simply echo'd each course name to keep it simple.

Comment: do you want to output only "course" names?

Comment: Easier to help with valid JSON.

Comment: Sorry AbraCadaver, I updated with valid JSON. I wrote it up on the spot for this hypothetical, although I will implement any potential answer if there is one. In this situation, I would generate a page for each degree that uses the name of the programs, degrees, courses, all on that page. I have a means of doing this, I just was wondering if there was a better way than doing a foreach tree.

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if the answer you gave fits my situation, and I get that I didn't explain it very well so that's my fault. I may be able to apply your answer in some way such that it would work, but I haven't had a good opportunity to check it out yet. Thank you though for taking the time on it. I will get back to it some time this month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how this fits in overall, but it recursively extracts the `name` items in order:

```
$result = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k) use(&$result) {
                                 if($k == 'name') { $result[] = $v; }
                             });

print_r($result);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => undergraduate
    [1] => elementary education
    [2] => math
)
```